# How can i set a timeout on google cloud datastore .get?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, try-catch

I'm just start with some google cloud services, and I'm trying to get a entity from datastore.

If the client have internet connection, everything its going well.

But i want to put a try catch statement for the cases were the client have no access to datastore, due any reason (like internet).

Here's my code:

```
try{
    let search = datastore.key(['Client', Client_id])           
    datastore.get(search, /*{timeout: 1000},*/ function (err, entity) {
        console.log('limit >>>', entity.limit)
        evt.emit('comparedate', res, entity.limit)    
    });
}
catch(error){
    console.log('Error >>>', error)
}
```

My problem is: there is no time limit for connection attempt. When the client have no access to the internet the request keep "pending" forever, and don't go to the catch condition.

I tried some parameters like: [Global#CallOptions](https://googleapis.github.io/gax-nodejs/global.html#CallOptions), but with no success.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT >>>> I know that's not the most trustworthy way. But for now I resolved with this code:

```
evt.on('isonline', (res) => {
    try{
        require('dns').lookup('google.com',function(err) {
            if (err && err.code == "ENOTFOUND") {
                console.log('NO INTERNET')
                evt.emit('readofflinedata', res)
            } else {
                console.log('WITH INTERNET')
                evt.emit('readonlinedata', res)
            }
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(200).send({ error: true, message: error.message })
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The Datastore client uses a library internally called [google-gax](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs). You can configure timeouts/etc. by passing in [gax options](https://googleapis.github.io/gax-nodejs/global.html#CallOptions).

```
datastore.get(key, {
  gaxOptions: {timeout: 1000}
}, (err, entity) => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found any parameter to add a timeout in the get function of datastore. However you can use a Promise and set a timer, if the execution of the function takes too long it will stop it.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var elt = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fun(param, (err) => {
     if (err) reject(err);
     doSomething(); // <- datastore.get() funtion
     resolve();
});

elt.timeout(1000).then(() => console.log('done'))
                 .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, (e) => console.log("timed out"))
```

Comment: Alex. I never work with promises before. I tried something like that:
let cloudDatasrore = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
 ...
 datastore.get(search, function (err, entity){
  console.log('Data limite >>>>>>>>', entity.limit)
 })
})
evt.on('readonlinedata', (res) => {
 cloudDatasrore.timeout(5000).then(()=>
 console.log('>>>>>>>>>> WORK')
 )
 .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, (e)=>
 console.log('>>>>>>>>>> NOT WORK', e)
 )
In that case I aways receive a "NOT WORK" message, and the request on browser network keep the "pending" status.
I've made something wrong?